# Testing for Balanced Delimiters using a Stack

Tags: java, stack, delimiter

I made a generic stack class based on a singly linked list and am trying to use it to check user input for balanced delimiters. I am just checking these delimiters: (){}[]

Stack Code

```
public class SLStack<T> {

//initializes the first node
private SLStackNode<T> head; //initializes the first node

//constructor initializes the first node as null to simulate an empty stack
public SLStack(){
    head = null;
}

//inner node class
public static class SLStackNode<T>{
    public T data;
    public SLStackNode<T> next;
}

//adds an element to the top of the stack
public void push(T value){
    SLStackNode<T> newNode = new SLStackNode<>();
    newNode.data = value;
    newNode.next = head;
    head = newNode;
}

//removes an element from the top of the stack
public T pop(){
    if (head == null){
        throw new IllegalStateException("The list is empty.");
    }
    T value = head.data;
    head = head.next;
    return value;
}

//checks the element at the top of the stack
public T top(){
    if (head == null){
        throw new IllegalStateException("The list is empty.");
    }
    T value = head.data;
    return value;
}

public boolean isEmpty(){
    return head ==  null;
}


public void printStack(SLStackNode<T> node, int depth) {
    if (node.next != null) {
        System.out.println(depth + " : " + node.data); //recurses through the stack
        //printStack(node.next);
    }
    System.out.println(depth + " : " + node.data); //recursive base case
}
}
```

Balance Tester Code

```
public class Balanced {
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    SLStack<ExpressionScanner.Token> delimStack = new SLStack<>();
    System.out.println("Enter one expression per line.");
    System.out.println("End the program with a period on a line by itself.");
    ExpressionScanner escan = new ExpressionScanner(new Scanner(System.in));
    while (escan.hasNext()) {
        ExpressionScanner.Token token = escan.next();

        if (token.getType() == ExpressionScanner.Token.Type.OP || token.getType() == ExpressionScanner.Token.Type.VAR){
            //ignore these tokens
            continue;
        }

        if (token.getType() == ExpressionScanner.Token.Type.DELIM_OPEN){
            //push opening delimiter to the stack
            delimStack.push(token);
        }

        if (token.getType() == ExpressionScanner.Token.Type.DELIM_CLOSE){
            //look for matching opening delimiter in the stack and pop it from the stack
            if (token == delimStack.top()){
                delimStack.pop();
            }else{
                throw new IllegalStateException("Imbalanced delimiter detected.");
            }
        }

        if (delimStack.isEmpty()){
            System.out.println("Delimiters are balanced.");
        }else{
            System.out.println("Imbalanced delimiter detected.");
        }

        //System.out.println(token);
    }
}
}
```

When I run the tester it always says that the delimiter is imbalanced no matter what it is. Even doing a single opening delimiter causes it to say there is an imbalance but it doesn't throw the exception. It throws the exception on a single closing delimiter or if there is more than one closing delimiters. If I have two opening delimiters it doesn't terminate either.

I can post the code for the ExpressionScanner also if anyone needs it.

Comment: Use a debugger for step-by-step inspection.

Answer (score 0):

```
            if (token == delimStack.top()){
            delimStack.pop();
        }else{
            throw new IllegalStateException("Imbalanced delimiter detected.");
        }
```

If I assumed correctly your code is throwing and exception here because it's expecting a token of type DELIM_CLOSE but receiving DELIM_OPEN (provided your input was '()').

What you should check is whether delimStack.pop() = token.type.DELIM_OPEN.